# how can I set a url as a prop without getting undefined in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, app-router

i have a file (handlers.ts) with a function for post data to a dynamic api route, im using app router,this function get values and url, for fetching, when i pass the url as a prop

http://localhost:3000/undefined+/address i got error post

this is my function for postdata

```
export async function PostFormData(values: FormType, url: string) {
  const req = await fetch(`${process.env.URL_FORM_DATA}+${url}`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(values),
    headers: {
      "content-type": "utf-8",
    },
  });
  if (!req.ok) {
    throw new Error("Error");
  }
  return console.log(req);
}
```

and this is my route handler in the api form/[categoryform]/route.ts

```
import { FormType } from "@/types/interface";

export async function POST(
  request: Request,
  { params }: { params: { categoryform: string } }
) {
  const categoryform = params.categoryform;
  switch (categoryform) {
    case "vote":
      const body: FormType = await request.json();
      return new Response(JSON.stringify(body), { status: 200 });
    case "address":
      const bodyaddress: FormType = await request.json();
      return new Response(JSON.stringify(bodyaddress), { status: 200 });
    default:
      return new Response(" No vote");
  }
}
```

the route is working perfectly with thunderclient

this is how i pass the data to the function

```
 const onFinish = (values: FormType) => {
    try {
      form.resetFields();
      const url  = "/address"
      PostFormData(values, url);
    } catch {
      setError(true);
      console.log("caca");
    }
  };
```

and i get this error POST http://localhost:3000/undefined+/address 404 (Not Found)

Note: if i use in onFinish the url as "http://localhost:3000/api/form/address" it work but i dont want this approach i want to able to pass the data as a prop and with an env var

ty all in advance

Comment: So `${process.env.URL_FORM_DATA}` is undefined... how did you add it to your env?

Comment: The problem was i wasnt setting the env as NEXT_PUBLIC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your code is correct except this:
Firstly check that you are getting `process.env.URL_FORM_DATA` value or not ?

If values are not getting from the `.env` file then try to add the `NEXT_PUBLIC_URL_FORM_DATA` in your env file and update the code accordingly.

And update the code with the below:

```
const req = await fetch(`${process.env.URL_FORM_DATA}${url}`, {
```

Let me know if still you are encountering issue.

Comment: This completely solved the problem, thank u